# Consulta HAVING SUM() en HQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

quisiera utilizar la siguiente consulta que realice en MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bdcsd.insumo
GROUP BY bdcsd.insumo.Nombre_Insumo
HAVING SUM(bdcsd.insumo.Stock_Actual) <= bdcsd.insumo.PDP;
```

En una clase java utilizando el metodo HQL Query de Hibernate, hice lo siguiente:

```
Query query = appMain.getSession().createQuery("from Insumo "
+ "group by Nombre_Insumo "
+ "having sum(Stock_Actual) <= PDP");
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:213)
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:171)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:432)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:85)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.extractDataType(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:241)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.initialize(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:64)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.prepareLogicOperator(HqlSqlWalker.java:1294)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4584)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2096)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.groupClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:618)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at controlador.ControladorITablaPDP.llenarTablaPDP(ControladorITablaPDP.java:139)
at controlador.ControladorICsd_Principal.mostrarPDP(ControladorICsd_Principal.java:445)
```

Comment: Por [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362251/new-object-with-hql-npe-on-standardansisqlaggregationfunctions-determinejdbct#18363301) del sitio en inglés, sospecho que te falta ponerle prefijo al nombre de la tabla para que la encuentre.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias, lo pude solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

```
Query query = appMain.getSession().createQuery("select ins "
                + "from Insumo ins "
                + "group by ins.nombreInsumo "
                + "having sum(ins.stockActual) <= ins.pdp");
```

Ya no hago referencia a los campos de insumo como estan escritos en mi BD, hago referencia a los campos de insumo como los tengo escrito en mi clase java.